# How do you lookup in range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup, isin

I have 2 data frames that I would like to return the values in a range (-1, 0, +1). One of the data frames contains Id's that i would like to look up and the other data frame contains Id's & values. For example, I want to lookup 99, 55, 117 in another data frame and return 100 99 98, 56 55 54, 118 117 116. As you can see it getting the values -1 and +1 of the Id's I would like to lookup. There is a better example below.

```
df    = pd.DataFrame([[99],[55],[117]],columns = ['Id'])

df2    = pd.DataFrame([[100,1,2,4,5,6,8],
               [87,1,6,20,22,23,34],
               [99,1,12,13,34,45,46],
               [64,1,10,14,29,32,33],
               [55,1,22,13,23,33,35],
               [66,1,6,7,8,9,10],
               [77,1,2,3,5,6,8],
               [811,1,2,5,6,8,10], 
               [118,1,7,8,22,44,56],
               [117,1,66,44,47,87,91]],
               columns = ['Id', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

I would like my result to something like this below.

```
results    = pd.DataFrame([[87,1,6,20,22,23,34],
               [99,1,12,13,34,45,46],
               [64,1,10,14,29,32,33],
               [64,1,10,14,29,32,33],
               [55,1,22,13,23,33,35],
               [66,1,6,7,8,9,10],
               [118,1,7,8,22,44,56],
               [117,1,66,44,47,87,91]],
               columns = ['Id', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

Comment: How should these values be related to integers -1 and 1 (or numbers between -1 and 1?)?

Comment: Yes I also tried `result= df2[(df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID']))]` but this only return the values. I'm looking for the value before and the values after.

Comment: @Chris what would be the expected output for df2 (show it)?

Comment: What do u mean. Is there a way to just return the Id that came before and after of the id im looking for? For example say if I wanted to lookup 55, 50, 34, is there a way to return 56 55 54, 51 50 49, 35 34 33 instead of the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


ind = df2[df2['Id'].isin(df['Id'])].index
aaa = np.array([[ind[i]-1,ind[i],ind[i]+1] for i in range(len(ind))]).ravel()
aaa = aaa[(aaa <= df2.index.values[-1]) & (aaa >= 0)]
df_test = df2.loc[aaa, :].reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)

print(df_test)
```

Output

```
    Id  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6
0   87     1     6    20    22    23    34
1   99     1    12    13    34    45    46
2   64     1    10    14    29    32    33
3   64     1    10    14    29    32    33
4   55     1    22    13    23    33    35
5   66     1     6     7     8     9    10
6  118     1     7     8    22    44    56
7  117     1    66    44    47    87    91
```

Here, in the `ind` list, indexes are obtained where there are the required Ids in df2.

The `aaa` list creates ranges for these indexes, then the lists are wrapped in `np.array`, `ravel()` is used to concatenate them. Next, the list `aaa` is overwritten, the elements that are greater than the maximum index `df2` are removed.

Sampling occurs through [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

**Update 17.12.2022**

if you need duplicate rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[99], [55], [117], [117]], columns=['Id'])
lim_ind = df2.index[-1]


def my_func(i):
    a = df2[df2['Id'].isin([i])].index.values
    a = np.array([a - 1, a, a + 1]).ravel()
    a = a[(a >= 0) & (a <= lim_ind)]

    return a


qqq = [my_func(i) for i in df['Id']]
fff = np.array([df2.loc[qqq[i]].values for i in range(len(qqq))], dtype=object)
fff = np.vstack(fff)
result = pd.DataFrame(fff, columns=df2.columns)

print(result)
```

Output

```
    Id  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6
0   87     1     6    20    22    23    34
1   99     1    12    13    34    45    46
2   64     1    10    14    29    32    33
3   64     1    10    14    29    32    33
4   55     1    22    13    23    33    35
5   66     1     6     7     8     9    10
6  118     1     7     8    22    44    56
7  117     1    66    44    47    87    91
8  118     1     7     8    22    44    56
9  117     1    66    44    47    87    91
```